# Show town, village, ... of a city (commune) from YQL

Tags: geolocation, yahoo, yql

I want to show the towns, villages, ... of a city by WOEID with YQL.
But I can't show the result! 
I tried with:

```
select * from geo.places where parent_woeid="12680570"
select * from geo.places where admin3.woeid="12680570"
select * from geo.places in (select * from geo.places where woeid="12680570")
select * from geo.places where woeid in (select * from geo.places where woeid="12680570")
select name, placeTypeName, admin3 from geo.places where content="Montichiari"
```

but I havent't solution!

Have you got a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your YQL query is wrong. The YQL query should be:
 `select * from geo.places where woeid="12680570"`

Try it out [here](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20woeid%3D%2212680570%22&diagnostics=false&format=json). Link to YQL console is [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+geo.places+where+woeid%3D%2212680570%22)